# Why does Math::BigInt has wrong output?

Tags: perl, bigint

I need to get the nearest number `$new` to `$orig` divisible by `$divisor`. The `$new` should be greater than `$orig`. So I have come with the following formula (hopefully, there is no error in it):

```
$new = $orig + ($divisor - $orig % $divisor)
```

Now, the `$orig` number is an integer and has up to 30 digits. I want to implement this into a Perl function using `Math::BigInt`, but the output is quite wrong.

```perl
use Math::BigInt;

Math::BigInt->accuracy(60);
Math::BigInt->precision(60);

my $orig = Math::BigInt->new('5967920747812842369477355441');  # A
my $divisor = Math::BigInt->new('719');                        # B
my $modulo = $orig->bmod($divisor);  # A % B = M
my $diff = $divisor->bsub($modulo);  # B - M = D
my $new = $orig->badd($diff);        # A + D = N
my $test = $new->bdiv($divisor);     # N / B = 0


print("orig : $orig\n");      # 10; should be: 5967920747812842369477355441
print("modulo : $modulo\n");  # 10; should be: 648
print("diff : $diff\n");      # 71; should be: 71
print("new : $new\n");        # 10; should be: 5967920747812842369477355512
print("test : $test\n");      # 10; should be: 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigInt#Arithmetic-methods : "These methods modify the invocand object and returns it."  In other words, `bmod`, `bsub`, and `badd` are like `%=`, `-=`, and `+=`, not like `%`, `-`, and `+`.

So everywhere where you call one of the arithmetic methods, you should copy first, so the object you are currently calling the method on isn't changed:

```
use Math::BigInt;

Math::BigInt->accuracy(60);
Math::BigInt->precision(60);

my $orig = Math::BigInt->new('5967920747812842369477355441');  # A
my $divisor = Math::BigInt->new('719');                        # B
my $modulo = $orig->copy->bmod($divisor);  # A % B = M
my $diff = $divisor->copy->bsub($modulo);  # B - M = D
my $new = $orig->copy->badd($diff);        # A + D = N
my $test = $new->copy->bmod($divisor);     # N % B = 0


print("orig : $orig\n");      # 10; should be: 5967920747812842369477355441
print("modulo : $modulo\n");  # 10; should be: 648
print("diff : $diff\n");      # 71; should be: 71
print("new : $new\n");        # 10; should be: 5967920747812842369477355512
print("test : $test\n");      # 10; should be: 0
```

(Also changed your test to do modulus, not division.)